# Editing the code according to some features

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

I have a homework and what homework wants from me;

1. Track length will be determined randomly by the program and will be
   between 50-100 meters. (50 and 100)
2. The competitor's Health Point (HP) is 100.
3. Obstacle number (Min: 2 Max: 5), and blocking the exit will be
   meters (Min: 5 ~ Max: Track Length) completely will be
   randomly determined by the program.
4. The contestant who encounters the obstacle; If the prime ranges
   between HP (HP) and the obstacle, The Life Point will drop by the
   meter encountered. (HP - = Meters Encountered) (It is obligatory to
   check the primality between HP and the meter where the obstacle
   exits by using the function)
5. If the competitor successfully passes the last obstacle (HP> 0), he
   will successfully finish the competition and win the grand prize.
   Will. If there is no Life Point (HP <= 0) after the obstacle, the
   game will be over and eliminated.
6. Each step will be recorded in the "log.txt" file
7. Use of features like program design (struct, pointer, dynamic memory, void or int) etc.
   It is important.

My Code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fk = fopen("log.TXT", "w");  //6- Log.TXT
    fprintf(fk,"The race started !!!\nContestant HP = 100\n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int big,small,i,j,t;
    //1- Parkur Length 50-100
    int TrackLength = 50+rand()%51;
    //2- HP 100
    int HP=100;
    // 3- Obstacles Number (Min:2 Max:5)Obstacle Meter (Min:5 ~ Max: TrackLength)
    int ObstaclesNumber=2+rand()%4;
    int ObstacleMeter[ObstaclesNumber];
    for(int x=0; x<ObstaclesNumber; x++){ ObstacleMeter[x]=5+rand()%TrackLength;}
    // Obstacle Meter Sort
    for (i = 0; i < ObstaclesNumber-1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < ObstaclesNumber-i-1; j++)
            if (ObstacleMeter[j] > ObstacleMeter[j+1]){
                t=ObstacleMeter[j];
                ObstacleMeter[j]=ObstacleMeter[j+1];
                ObstacleMeter[j+1] = t;}
    // 4- HP Change
    for(int z=0; z<ObstaclesNumber; z++){
        if (ObstacleMeter[z] > HP){big = ObstacleMeter[z],small = HP;}
        else{big = HP,small = ObstacleMeter[z];}
            for(int dividing=2; dividing<=small/2; dividing++){
                if( (big % dividing == 0) && (small % dividing == 0) ){
                    fprintf(fk,"The competitor did not find any obstacles up to %d meters\nThere is one obstacle at %d meters. It is not prime between %d and %d\n", ObstacleMeter[z], ObstacleMeter[z], HP, ObstacleMeter[z]);
                    fprintf(fk,"\nContestant HP = %d\n",HP);
                    break;}
                else{
                    fprintf(fk,"The competitor did not find any obstacles up to %d meters\nThere is one obstacle at %d meters. It is prime between %d and %d\n", ObstacleMeter[z], ObstacleMeter[z], HP, ObstacleMeter[z]);
                    HP -= ObstacleMeter[z];
                    fprintf(fk,"\nContestant HP = %d\n",HP);
                    if(HP<=0){ // 5- Hp<0 Control
                        fprintf(fk,"Sorry !!! You could not complete the contest.\n");
                        exit(0);}
                    break;}
                    break;}}
    fprintf(fk,"Congratulations !!! You finished the competition with %d HP.\n",HP);
}
```

The program I do is working but it is specified in the homework (7) ('struct' 'pointer' 'dynamic memory' 'int or void') etc. I did not use the features, I don't know how to use them in this code

can you help edit the code

Sample Output;

```
The race started !!!
Contestant HP = 100
The competitor did not find any obstacles up to 56 meters
There is one obstacle at 56 meters. It is not prime between 100 and 56

Contestant HP = 100
The competitor did not find any obstacles up to 62 meters
There is one obstacle at 62 meters. It is not prime between 100 and 62

Contestant HP = 100
The competitor did not find any obstacles up to 63 meters
There is one obstacle at 63 meters. It is prime between 100 and 63

Contestant HP = 37
Congratulations !!! You finished the competition with 37 HP.
```

Comment: My guess is your teacher does not want you to use VLAs (Variable Length Arrays), change `int ObstacleMeter[ObstaclesNumber]` to use dynamic memory allocation. You can group all your game properties (obstacle number, hp etc...) into a struct to get the other requirement. Seems redundant to me.

Comment: Not sure how `void` or `int` is to be addressed in concert with allocating dynamic memory for a struct.??

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Read the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (maybe [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)). StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website. See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fk = NULL;
    int big, small, i, j, t, x, z, TrackLength, HP, ObstaclesNumber, dividing;
    int *ObstacleMeter = NULL;

    if( (fk  = fopen("log.TXT", "w")) == NULL ) //6- Log.TXT
    {
        perror("log.TXT");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fk, "The race started !!!\nContestant HP = 100\n");

    srand(time(NULL));

    //1- Parkour Length 50-100
    TrackLength = 50+rand()%51;
    //2- HP 100
    HP=100;
    // 3- Obstacles Number (Min:2 Max:5)Obstacle Meter (Min:5 ~ Max: TrackLength)
    ObstaclesNumber=2+rand()%4;

    if( (ObstacleMeter = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * ObstaclesNumber)) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Memory Unavailable.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(x = 0; x < ObstaclesNumber; x++)
        ObstacleMeter[x] = 5 + rand() % TrackLength;

    // Obstacle Meter Sort
    for (i = 0; i < (ObstaclesNumber - 1); i++)
        for (j = 0; j < (ObstaclesNumber - i - 1); j++)
            if (ObstacleMeter[j] > ObstacleMeter[j+1])
            {
                t = ObstacleMeter[j];
                ObstacleMeter[j] = ObstacleMeter[j+1];
                ObstacleMeter[j+1] = t;
            }

    // 4- HP Change
    for(z = 0; z < ObstaclesNumber; z++)
    {
        if (ObstacleMeter[z] > HP)
        {
            big = ObstacleMeter[z];
            small = HP;
        }
        else
        {
            big = HP;
            small = ObstacleMeter[z];
        }
        for(dividing = 2; dividing <= (small/2); dividing++)
        {
            if( (big % dividing == 0) && (small % dividing == 0) )
            {
                fprintf(fk, "The competitor did not find any obstacles up to %d meters\nThere is one obstacle at %d meters. It is not prime between %d and %d\n", ObstacleMeter[z], ObstacleMeter[z], HP, ObstacleMeter[z]);
                fprintf(fk, "\nContestant HP = %d\n", HP);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fk, "The competitor did not find any obstacles up to %d meters\nThere is one obstacle at %d meters. It is prime between %d and %d\n", ObstacleMeter[z], ObstacleMeter[z], HP, ObstacleMeter[z]);
                HP -= ObstacleMeter[z];
                fprintf(fk, "\nContestant HP = %d\n", HP);
                if(HP <= 0)
                {
                    // 5- Hp<0 Control
                    fprintf(fk, "Sorry !!! You could not complete the contest.\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
            }
        }
    fprintf(fk,"Congratulations !!! You finished the competition with %d HP.\n",HP);
    fclose(fk);
    free(ObstacleMeter);
    return 0;
}
```

Read about `Dynamic memory allocation` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/).

Read about `Pointers in C` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/).

The above code is similar to the C code written according to `C89 standard`.

Changes made to the code:

```
 1. All variable declarations are at the top.
 2. Error-checking while opening the file.
 3. Proper spacing & indenting.
 4. Declaring ObstacleMeter as an int * and allocating memory to it dynamically.
 5. Error-checking while allocating memory to the variable.
 6. Closing opened log.txt file.
 7. Freeing allocated memory to ObstacleMeter.
 8. return 0;
```

Comment: my teacher shared such a message; Codes written without using a function (Hard coded) will not be accepted. (Each step will be done with the function.), is this code in the (hardcoded) category ?

Comment: Do you know what hard-coding is? @AomineDaici

Comment: _Hard coding is the software development practice of embedding data directly into the source code of a program or other executable object, as opposed to obtaining the data from external sources or generating it at run-time._ -source Wikipedia

Comment: So, if in your program you are doing like this ```int arr[2] = {1, 2};```. This is hard-coding. Code written without functions aren't really hard-coded. Rather writing functions in your program defines the concept of ```modular programming```.

Comment: Similar to the ```divide & conquer technique```. You divide a problem into its subsection( which are functions) and solve them seperately(codin them) and then you integrate all solutions to get the original solution of the problem.

Comment: Therefore, In this program, if you can remove some line and make a functions for them this'll be called modular programming. Like you can make a function named ```allocate``` to allocate memory to the pointer variable. It's up to you, how you wanna make function?, what will be the functionality? @AomineDaici

Comment: I don't know, I just wrote the message that the teacher shared, if there is no problem accordingly, we don't need to do anything

Answer (score 2):

*specified in the homework (7) ('struct' 'pointer' 'dynamic memory' 'int or void') etc. I did not use the features, I don't know how to use them in this code*

Here is an example of creating space (dynamically allocated memory) for 15 instances of the `struct` `tData`:

```
#define DATA_SIZE 15

typedef struct {
   int a;
   float b;
}tData;

int main(void)
{
    tData *data = malloc(DATA_SIZE*sizeof(*data));
    if(data)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<DATA_SIZE;i++)
        {
            data[i].a = i+1;    //assign valus to members of all 15 instances
            data[i].b = i*(1.0);
        }
        //use struct, then free
        free(data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can mark 1 answer right, + I gave the vote

Comment: @AomineDaici - You are welcome!  Your question was fairly well formed, but I never saw a response to my question (oin comments under your post.) about `void` or `int` and how they needed to play into the answer.  Can you tell me that?

Comment: There is no explanation about this, it is not compulsory to write the code like this, but if it is written like this, + points, maybe my teacher might want us to get a prime number or sort using 'void' as an example